# Elastic Search need to return only 1 field from a range.

Tags: elasticsearch

Just getting started with curl and Elastic Search queries. I have this query:

```
{
  "query": {
           "range": {
                    "_timestamp": {
                            "gt": "now-30m"
        }
      }
    }
}'
```

It works great, but returns all data from that 30 min window. How do I go about refining the search to only return the ID field?

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called source filtering https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html

```
{
  "_source": [ "ID" ],
  "query": {
           "range": {
                    "_timestamp": {
                            "gt": "now-30m"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much.